# Excel - Split characters

Tags: excel, vba

I want to split the characters of a cell into columns.
For example if cell A1 is the number 5678, then I want to transform it to B1=5, B2=6, B3=7, B4=8.

How can I do this? I tried with =MID($A1, COLUMNS($A$1:A$1), 1)

However this split the characters into different cells in a row.

I do not mind if it will be done by formula or VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
B1:  =MID($A1,COLUMNS($A:A),1)
```

and fill right

In your original post, you indicated you wanted to split the value into columns.  If you want to split it into separate rows, then, change columns to rows:

```
 B1:  =MID($A$1,ROWS($1:1),1)
```

and fill down.

Comment: I want to fill down, not right. If I fill it down it does not give correct answer.

Comment: You wrote that you wanted to split the cell into columns.  To fill down, change `COLUMNS` to `ROWS($1:1)`

Comment: i don't know what I am doing wrong, but it still not working :/

Comment: Okay, I found it. Thank you